# Custom object in .NET

Tags: .net, console-application

I have an array of objects which contains various kinds of data in it, like int, string, bool. I need to get the individual records from the object.

I need to store them in a class.

I know I have to use generics, how to do that?

Comment: does the array have information for only one object that you want to create?

Comment: for me, personally, to be able to understand the question, you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a class (eg, `MyRecord`) with the properties you need, then make a generic `List<MyRecord>` instance to hold the class instances.

Answer (score 0):

Generics wouldn't work for you as they are just compiler magic. You can look at DynamicObject or ExpandoObject for what you need.

Alternatively you can build a dynamic object as well. Look at System.CodeDom namespace. Here's an example

```
public class DynamicCodeCompiler
{
    public static Type CompileCode(string code, string typeName)
    {
        var compiler = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("c#");
        var compilerResults = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(new CompilerParameters(), code);
        if (compilerResults.Errors.HasErrors) return null;
        return compilerResults.CompiledAssembly.GetType(typeName);
    }

    public static Type CreateClass(string nameSpaceName, string className, IDictionary<string, Type> properties)
    {
        var imports = new CodeNamespaceImportCollection();
        foreach (var value in properties.Values)
        {
            imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport(value.Namespace));
        }
        imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport("System"));

        var @class = new CodeTypeDeclaration(className)
                         {
                             IsClass = true
                         };
        foreach (var propertyDefinition in properties)
        {
            var backingField = CreateBackingField(propertyDefinition.Key, propertyDefinition.Value);
            @class.Members.Add(backingField);
            var property = new CodeMemberProperty();
            property.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;
            property.Name = propertyDefinition.Key;
            property.Type = new CodeTypeReference(propertyDefinition.Value);
            property.GetStatements.Add(new CodeMethodReturnStatement(new CodeSnippetExpression(backingField.Name)));
            property.SetStatements.Add(new CodeAssignStatement(new CodeSnippetExpression(backingField.Name),
                new CodePropertySetValueReferenceExpression()));
            @class.Members.Add(property);
        }

        var nameSpace = new CodeNamespace(nameSpaceName);
        nameSpace.Types.Add(@class);
        var assembly = new CodeCompileUnit();
        //Add the namespace to the assembly.
        assembly.Namespaces.Add(nameSpace);
        var compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.dll" })
                                     {GenerateInMemory = true};
        //compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");

        var compiler = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("c#");
        var compilerResults = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromDom(compilerParameters, assembly);
        if (compilerResults.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            foreach (var error in compilerResults.Errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error);
            }
            return null;
        }
        var codeText = new StringWriter();
        compiler.GenerateCodeFromNamespace(nameSpace, new IndentedTextWriter(codeText), new CodeGeneratorOptions());
        return compilerResults.CompiledAssembly.GetType(string.Format("{0}.{1}", nameSpaceName, className));
    }

    private static CodeMemberField CreateBackingField(string name, Type type)
    {
        return new CodeMemberField
                   {
                       Attributes = MemberAttributes.Private,
                       Name = string.Format("_{0}", name),
                       Type = new CodeTypeReference(type)
                   };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the position of the data in the array, then you could simply do this:

1. Create a class with all the attributes you want
2. myObject.name = array[0]; myObject.age = array[1];